# My Javascript code does not work in IE but works fine in other browsers

Tags: javascript, password-protection

I used the following Javascript to password protect my webpage but it's not working for IE, although it works fine for Chrome and Firefox.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var password;
    var pass1="PASSWORD-HERE";
    password=prompt('Whats The Magic Word?',' ');
    if (password==pass1) alert('That Is Correct!');
    else {
      window.location="SITE-LINK";
    }
</script>
```

What is wrong?

Please check out the link: http://www.xuanyinwen.com/test3.html
it work on Firefox and chrome but not IE, when you open the link in IE, it got no message pot up asking for the password, and will automatic go to SITE-LINK. 
I know this script is not very secure, but I just want use it for a basic protect, just want make it work. thanks for any help!

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? What is it doing instead of what you expected?

Comment: It is **impossible** to "protect" a web page with nothing but JavaScript code.

Comment: And the `language` attribute has been deprecated long ago. Use the `type` attribute (or nothing in HTML 5) instead.

Comment: Hi there, please check the original question again, I just add more details and a test page for it. cheers for any help.

Comment: LOL I am unable to retrieve the source code of the page above.

Comment: if you open it with Chrome, it will work fine. but not IE. no idea why. cheer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    prompt('Password:') === '1234' ? 
        alert('Correct!') : 
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
</script>
```

The difference is that you are setting the `href` property instead.

btw I tested this in IE9 beta and it works.

Comment: i have a feeling its her IE browser setting because i tried the javascript and it works for me in IE7/8/quirk mode.

Comment: I just try your script but its still the same for me, work in firefox and chrome, but not IE. any idea why please

Comment: @xuan Which version of IE are you testing in?

Comment: IE 8, version:8.0.6001.18975.

Comment: @xuan An what exactly happens in IE?

Comment: for using your script it will go to the google.com page automatically. nothing come up for asking password. cheers

Comment: @xuan Does this redirect you automatically in IE? http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/prompt.html

Comment: yes, no idea why the javascript looks not working in my IE. cheers

Answer (score 0):

i personally wouldn't just use javascript for password protection...especially when it can be displayed publically.

Check to see if active x is diabled.  works on IE 7/8 and quirk mode for me

IE Turn off popup-block and auto enable active x:

open IE go to Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Security make sure allow active x are allowed.  Then go to Tools->Internet Options->privacy and make sure pop up is not blocked.

WARNING: I DO NOT RECOMMAND DOING THIS! AFTER TESTING PLEASE USE DEFAULT I WILL NOT BE RESPONSIBLE

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I know its not very secure for the script, but I just use it for basic protect. could you let me know where I can check active x diable, is it on IE option? thanks again.

Comment: I have enable the active x but still no luck to make it work on IE. cheers

Comment: @xuanyinwen i just don't think you should continue going this route unless its absolutely necessary to accomplish what you are attempting to do.  Also, make sure your IE is set to default setting and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var password;
var pass1="PASSWORD-HERE";
password = prompt('Whats The Magic Word?',' ');
if (password === pass1)
    alert('That Is Correct!');
else
    window.location="SITE-LINK";
</script>
```

The difference being 3 equals signs instead of 2.  Double-equals in JavaScript lets the runtime try to do type coercion on the items being compared, while with three equals it compares them exactly as-is.

However, as the commenter above noted, using javascript as your only password protection is naive at best.

Comment: That shouldn't make it fail, in this case.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your idea, but it still not work for IE after I change it. any other idea please? cheers

Comment: Working fine on IE8 for me. And Marcel is correct - my modification doesn't make a bit of difference.  Perhaps if you could enlighten us as to "what" is not working for you that would help.

Comment: could you check the orginal description, I add more detail about how it fail to work on IE and make an test page as well. thanks

Comment: And the test page works correctly in IE for me, using the password "wen"

Comment: i have a feeling she's not allowing popups in IE browser setting and in term causes the prompt window to not 'prompt'

Comment: now no once can view the source any more, so do you guys think its secure now? cheers

Comment: Nope.  Turn off Javascript and I can still view the source.  Anything you do client-side in JS to secure a page is not truly secure.  The only way to do it "right" is server-side username/password validation.

Comment: ok, thanks, any one can give me some idea why not working in IE please.